# Inializing class members based on condition

Tags: c#

I have two types of users coming to my application which is a search tool that allows users to search medical records based on patient's information.

**1. Physician:** they can search based on `patientid` and `hospitalid`
**2. Police:** they can search based on `patientid`, `hospitalid`, `firstname` and `lastname`.

I am planning to create just one class for search criteria like this:

```
public class searchcriteria
{
  int? patientid
  int? hospitalid
  string firstname
  string lastname
}
```

How should I enforce the rule that `Patient` user types just initialize two properties?
Is this a good design to keep searchcriteria in one class or should it be separate entirely for `Patient` and `Police`? (in this case if new user comes in I need to add one more class)

Comment: You probably want to make those `int?` (nullable).

Comment: I assume those people are going to use a GUI, why don't you show the appropriate GUI controls according to their status? Then make those `strings` *optional* parameters.

Comment: this can be made nullable. but will merging search options for police and patient is a good design. how to ensure that patient does not by mistake set the first name or last name.

Answer (score 2):

You could create two different constructors for the type, one for two of the fields and one for all four, but that doesn't make it all that clear to callers which should be used when.  More clarity is added by having static factory methods for creating instances of the type:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    //prevent construction without using a factory method
    private SearchCriteria() { }
    public int? PatientId { get; private set; }
    public int? HospitalId { get; private set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public static SearchCriteria CreatePatientSearch(
        int? patendId, int? hospitalId)
    {
        return new SearchCriteria()
        {
            PatientId = patendId,
            HospitalId = hospitalId
        };
    }
    public static SearchCriteria CreatePoliceSearch(
        int? patendId, int? hospitalId,
        string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        return new SearchCriteria()
        {
            PatientId = patendId,
            HospitalId = hospitalId,
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
        };
    }
}
```

And of course once an object is constructed we no longer need to care whether it's a Patient or a Police search, we just act on the search criteria that have a value.  (When doing this it's important that the default value of each field mean "don't search on it" for this to work.)

Comment: The class defined above might be violating the single responsibility principle. it is acting like search criteria but also controlling its creation logic and hiding constructor.

Comment: @user3681134 This model is virtually identical to just having two public constructors instead of static methods, it's just giving those two constructors different names.  If you *really* want to, you could pull them out into multiple types (if you wanted to do so, I'd have an interface defining all search criteria and then any number of types implementing it, defining constructors only for the fields they intend to allow being set).  I don't see any real functional difference between the two options though, and this is less work to write.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a base search criteria available to Physicians and then a more specialized search criteria for Police, you can use inheritance as so:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
   public SearchCriteria(int patientId, int hospitalId)
   {
       PatientId = patientId;
       HospitalId = hospitalId;
   }

   public int PatientId {get;set;}
   public int HospitalId {get;set;}
}

public class PoliceSearchCriteria : SearchCriteria
{
   public PoliceSearchCriteria(int patientId, int hospitalId, string first, string last) 
   : base(patientId, hospitalId)
   {
       FirstName = first;
       LastName = last;
   }

   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: This isn't particularly well designed.  When creating a search criteria you need to cast it to the derived type in order to access the data to set the given fields, and for the search code to use the given filters it needs to check the type of the object, cast it if needed, and then pull out the given fields.  That's all pretty poor (and error prone) design.

Comment: in this case if tomorrow i want to add one more parameter which is applicable only to Patient user type not to Police user type this will fail like for Patient i include one more parameter WardNumber but this is not available to Police for searching.

Comment: @user3681135: In that case you would need to create the PatientSearchCriteria class that inherits from SearchCriteria to extend the functionality.

Comment: the whole point is that the search parameter can change for the classes. but if i follow this approach i might need to change the base class for PatientSearchCriteria. Do you think this will help

Comment: If you do use inheritance you will need to keep the base class SearchCriteria closed to modification, but open to extension. You can change and extend sub classes. You may find it helpful to your problem. But Servy has a point and it is not as efficient as using a single class.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider searchcriteria a pure data class, it is not its concern to enforce this kind of constraint.

Perhaps you can create two separate methods to perform the search, one for searching by `patientid` and `hospitalid`, and one for searching by all fields. Put them in separate interfaces (e.g. `IRestrictedSearch` and `IFullSearch`, or `IPhysicianSearch` and `IPoliceSearch`) and ensure that you only give the appropriate one will be available to the code that performs physician / police searches.

Answer (score 0):

I would like more info to get to know your issue better...

But if I get ir right, you have to different kind of users, and each one of them can make a search based on different criteria, is that ok??

This is what I'll do to solve this.

1. Get the user's role (to see if he/she is a phusician or police.
2. Once I get the user's role I'll make a conditional holding the different option for each user. On .Net VB It will something like this:

(Code for Default.aspx.vb)

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    Dim sRol As String = Roles.GetRolesForUser.Single()
    Dim sUser As String = User.Identity.Name

    If sRol = "Phyisician" Then

        Dim searchUrl As String = "search.aspx?searchprm=" & searchTB.Text & "susrrol=1"
        Response.Redirect(searchUrl)

    End If

    If sRol = "Police" Then

        Dim searchUrl As String = "search.aspx?searchprm=" & searchTB.Text & "susrrol=2"
        Response.Redirect(searchUrl)

    End If

End Sub
```

Then, on the search results page I will handle the code with different SQL stored procedures:

(search.aspx.vb)

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sRol As String = Roles.GetRolesForUser.Single()
    Dim sUser As String = User.Identity.Name

    If sRol = "Phyisician" Then

        Dim searchUrl As String = "search.aspx?searchprm=" & searchTB.Text & "susrrol=1"
        Response.Redirect(searchUrl)

    End If

    If sRol = "Police" Then

        Dim searchUrl As String = "search.aspx?searchprm=" & searchTB.Text & "susrrol=2"
        Response.Redirect(searchUrl)

    End If

    Dim prm As String = Request.QueryString("searchprm").ToString
    Dim rus As String = Request.QueryString("susrrol").ToString

    If rus = 1 Then

        Dim CountResults As String
        Dim strConn1 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YourConnection").ToString
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("SEL_COUNT_Hits_Rol1", New SqlConnection(strConn1))
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd1.Connection.Open()
        Dim sP1 As New SqlParameter("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sP1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        sP1.Value = prm
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(sP1)
        CountResults = String.Format("{0:##,###.##}", cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
        cmd1.Connection.Close()
        lblHits.Text = "<i>We have found " & CountResults & " patients who match your search terms:" & "</i>"

    End If

    If rus = 2 Then

        Dim CountResults As String
        Dim strConn1 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("YourConnection").ToString
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("SEL_COUNT_Hits_Rol2", New SqlConnection(strConn1))
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd1.Connection.Open()
        Dim sP1 As New SqlParameter("@search", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        sP1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        sP1.Value = prm
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(sP1)
        CountResults = String.Format("{0:##,###.##}", cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
        cmd1.Connection.Close()
        lblHits.Text = "<i>We have found " & CountResults & " patients who match your search terms:" & "</i>"

    End If

End Sub
```

Then, on the front code I'll bind a gridview with the found date. Probably, the SQL Query would be something like this (for rol 1 - physicians):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Patients] WHERE([PId] = @prm)
```

And for the gridview:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Patients] WHERE([PId] = @prm) ORDER BY [PId] ASC
```

And for the police (rol 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Patients] WHERE(FREETEXT(*, @prm))
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Patients] WHERE(FREETEXT(*, @prm)) ORDER BY [PId] ASC
```

I hope this give you some clue on how to solve this.